# Python- performance issue with mysql and google play subscription

Tags: python, performance, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to extract the `purchase_state` from google play, following the steps bellow:

```
    import base64
    import requests
    import smtplib
    from collections import OrderedDict
    import mysql.connector
    from mysql.connector import errorcode
    ......
```

> 1. Query db ,returning thousand of lines with `purchase_id`field from my table
> 2. Check for each row from db, and extract purchase_id, then query google play for all of them. for example if the results of my previous
>      step is 1000, 1000 times is querying google (refresh token + query).
> 3. Add a new field `purchase status` from the google play to a new dictionary apart from some other fields whcih are grabbed from mysql query.
> 4. The last step is doing a loop over my dic as a follow and prepare the desirable report

AFTER EDITED:

```
def build_dic_from_db(data,access_token):
dic = {}
for row in data:

    product_id = row['product_id']
    purchase_id = row['purchase_id']
    status = check_purchase_status(access_token, product_id,purchase_id)
    cnt = 1

    if row['user'] not in dic:
        dic[row['user']] = {'id':row['user_id'],'country': row['country_name'],'reg_ts': row['user_registration_timestamp'],'last_active_ts': row['user_last_active_action_timestamp'],
                            'total_credits': row['user_credits'],'total_call_sec_this_month': row['outgoing_call_seconds_this_month'],'user_status':row['user_status'],'mobile':row['user_mobile_phone_number_num'],'plus':row['user_assigned_msisdn_num'],
                            row['product_id']:{'tAttemp': cnt,'tCancel': status}}
    else:
        if row['product_id'] not in dic[row['user']]:
            dic[row['user']][row['product_id']] = {'tAttemp': cnt,'tCancel':status}
        else:
            dic[row['user']][row['product_id']]['tCancel'] += status
            dic[row['user']][row['product_id']]['tAttemp'] += cnt
return dic
```

The problem is that my code is working slowly ~ Total execution time: 448.7483880519867 and I am wondering if there is away to improve my script. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: The bottleneck seems to come from the google play request. Have you considered creating several executors to query the db in separate threads?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre hey, can u please explain it a little bit more, what does that mean, I am new to python! To notify u, I have only one sql query to mysql without filtering, then i am going through all the purchase_id and i am querying the google per each purchase. I didn't apply any filtering in mysql, as my query is huge enough and I tried to build my filtering in my dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm right about this, but the bottleneck seems to be the connection to the playstore. Doing it sequentially will take a long time, whereas the server is able to take a million requests at a time. So here's a way to process your jobs with executors (you need the "concurrent" package installed)
In that example, you'll be able to send 100 requests at the same time.

```
from concurrent import futures
EXECUTORS = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100)
jobs = dict()
for row in data:

   product_id = row['product_id']
   purchase_id = row['purchase_id']
   job = EXECUTORS.submit(check_purchase_status,
access_token, product_id,purchase_id)
   jobs[job] = row

for job in futures.as_completed(jobs.keys()):
   # here collect your results and do something useful with them :)
   status = job.result()
   # make the connection with current row
   row = jobs[job]
   # now you have your status and the row
```

And BTW try to use temp variables or you're constantly accessing your dictionary with the same keys, which is not good for performance AND readability of your code.

Comment: It seems to be great! I am going to try with my case. I would like to be sure about one thing, in each row I have only one purchase id, so in each time i am going to send only one purchase_id to the google, Do u think this solution would work in my case? I though that your case would be great with the a list of purchase_id not with one only! What 's your opinion?

Comment: That's the point: send 1000 requests without being blocked by google response time, just like 1000 users would do at the same time.

Comment: I have edited my question, I can not understand how can I send 1000 requests, shall I change the way i have written my function?